# idiomatic way to describe an approximate time during a stated month

Tags: phrase-request

What is the best idiomatic way to point out an approximate time that happened during a month?

For example:

> During the first semester he was basically passive and just observing
> things. During the second semester, however, there was a small change
> in him **somewhere in April** when he began participating in small
> discussions in class and became more active in team competitions.

1. "sometime in April" ?
2. "somewhere during April"?
3. "somewhere in April"?
4. "sometime during April"?
5. something else?

Comment: *sometime in April* is the most idiomatic.  I might use *somewhere* to hint that he was a bit lost.  I would avoid *somewhere during* as it breaks the time-is-space metaphor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anton Sherwood is right in his comment. “Where” is associated with space, not with time. The use of “where” in any form is not appropriate for a period of time. Use terms such as “when”, “during” and “sometime”. So 1 and 4 are correct.